# Is Haskell's bind operator (>>=) equivalent to F#'s forward pipe operator (|>)?

Tags: haskell, f#, bind, monads, pipeline

Type signature of Haskell's bind operator (>>=):

```
m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Type signature of F#'s forward pipe operator (|>):

```
'a -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b
```

They look similar.
And considering the impure nature of F#,
the equivalent operator of `|>` in Haskell is `>>=`?

For example:

Haskell:

```
getLine >>= putStrLn
```

F#:

```
stdin.ReadLine() |> stdout.Write
```

Comment: No. `|>` is like `$`. `>>=` is like `*.collect`, but generalised.

Comment: Potential close voters: this is definitely not opinion-based. It is possible to answer it objectively by considering the involved types and the differences between the languages (cf. the existing answers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really. If you specialize `m` to `IO`, then there are some superficial similarities, so maybe it’s true that `(>>=) @IO` *is* sort of like F#’s `|>`, but in general, the similarity does not hold.

If we specialize `m` to `Maybe`, then `>>=` is like `Option.bind`, just with the arguments flipped (which makes sense, since `>>=` is pronounced “bind”).

```
ghci> Just [1, 2, 3] >>= headMay
Just 1
ghci> Just [] >>= headMay
Nothing
ghci> Nothing >>= headMay
Nothing
```

If we specialize `m` to `Either e`, then `>>=` does something similar to what it does for `Maybe`, short-circuiting on `Left` values instead of `Nothing`. These examples are sort of similar to using `|>` with functions that raise exceptions, but they aren’t quite the same.

If we specialize `m` to `Parser` (from, say, the `megaparsec` package), then `>>=` produces a new parser that runs a first parser, then uses its result to determine which parser to run next. For example, this defines a parser that produces a parser that parses two digits or a non-digit followed by an arbitrary character:

```
p :: Parser Char
p = anyChar >>= \c -> if isDigit c then digit else anyChar
```

This is rather different from `|>`, since we’re not running anything, merely building up a structure (a parser) that will be applied to a value later, yet the code still talks about the value that will eventually be provided (in the `c` binding).

If we specialize `m` to `(->) r`, then `>>=` implements a kind of implicit argument passing. For example, if we have a set of functions that all accept a common argument:

```
f :: Key -> String
g :: String -> Key -> Char
h :: Char -> Key -> Bool
```

…then we can use `>>=` to compose them together, passing the same first argument to all of them:

```
ghci> :t f >>= g >>= h
f >>= g >>= h :: Key -> Bool
```

This is *clearly* different from `|>`, since we’re performing a sort of function composition, not function application.

I could go on, but listing dozens of examples probably isn’t any more helpful than just listing a few. The takeaway is that `>>=` is not just for sequencing effectful things, it is a much more general abstraction of which sequencing `IO` actions is a special case. The `IO` case is pragmatically useful, of course, but it’s also probably the least theoretically interesting, since it’s a little bit magical (`IO` is baked into the runtime). These other uses of `>>=` are not magical in the slightest; they are defined entirely using ordinary, pure Haskell code, but they’re still very useful, so they’re much more relevant to understanding the essence of `>>=` and `Monad` than `IO` is.

---

As a final aside, Haskell *does* have a function just like F#’s `|>`. It is called `&`, and it comes from the `Data.Function` module. It has the same type that it does in F#:

```
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```

This function is quite useful in its own right, but it has nothing to do with monads.

Comment: 1) The `Key` thing doesn’t work out: a) We need `f :: Key -> String` and b) `Key` should be the second argument to the other two (or `(<*>)` should be used). 2) `(>>=)` (really `(=<<)`) is a form of application. There’s a tower of power: `($)`/`(&)` for pure functions; `(<$>)` for `Functor`; `(<*>)`/`(<**>)` for `Applicative`; `(=<<)`/`(>>=)` for `Monad`.

Comment: @HTNW For your first point: yes, you’re right, I have no idea what I was thinking. I’ve updated the example to be what I imagine I originally had in mind. As for your second point, I agree, but I think it’s outside the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 9):

While F# doesn't distinguish between pure and impure operations, it does have the notion of monads. This is most observable when you work with [computation expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions). In order to implement a computation expression, you must implement *monadic bind*. In the F# documentation, this must have the type `M<'T> * ('T -> M<'U>) -> M<'U>`, although this is pseudo-code, since a type like `M<'T>` isn't proper F# syntax.

F# comes with some built-in monads, such as `Async<'a>`, `'a list`, `'a seq`. You can also trivially create computation expression for `'a option` and `Result`, although I don't think any of those are built in.

You can peruse the source code for the various computation expression builders to identify how monadic bind is implemented for each, but `AJFarmar` is right that they're often called `collect`:

```
> List.collect;;
val it : (('a -> 'b list) -> 'a list -> 'b list)

> Array.collect;;
val it : (('a -> 'b []) -> 'a [] -> 'b [])

> Seq.collect;;
val it : (('a -> #seq<'c>) -> seq<'a> -> seq<'c>)
```

Not always, though. Sometimes the operation is called `bind`:

```
> Option.bind;;
val it : (('a -> 'b option) -> 'a option -> 'b option)
```

To illustrate, consider this little F# helper function to parse a string into an integer:

```
open System

let tryParse s =
    match Int32.TryParse s with
    | true, i -> Some i
    | _ -> None
```

You can use the forward pipe if you have a string:

```
> "42" |> tryParse;;
val it : int option = Some 42
```

On the other hand, if your string is already is in an `option` value, you'd have to use monadic bind:

```
> Some "42" |> Option.bind tryParse;;
val it : int option = Some 42
```

The `|>` operator also exists in Haskell, but you have to import `Data.Function`:

```
Prelude Data.Function> :t (&)
(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
```